# spying on a dependency in a nodejs unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm using mocha and sinon for nodejs unit tests. I have the following

**users.js**

```
const Database = require('./lib/Database');

exports.setupNewUser = (name) => {
  var user = {
    name: name
  };

  try {
    Database.save(user);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error('something failed');
  }
}
```

**Database.js**

```
exports.save = (user) => {
  console.log(`saving: ${user}`);
};
```

**userTest.js**

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
require('chai').should();

const users = require('../src/users');

describe('users', () => {
  it('should log an error when the Database save fails', () => {
    var databaseSpy = sinon.spy(Database, 'save').throws(); // this is supposed to work??
    users.setupNewUser('Charles');
    databaseSpy.should.be.called;
  });
});
```

According to the sinon [tutorials](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js) I've read, I should be able to create that `databaseSpy` but I keep getting this error: ReferenceError: Database is not defined

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it might be a pathing issue. Your require might not be getting the correct path.

> **users.js**
>
> `const Database = require('./lib/Database');`

Where is /lib/Database in relation with the users.js file? I think that might be a good place to start looking.